# Partitions and Volumes in RHEL5

Tags: linux

What is the difference between a Partition and a Volume in Redhat Linux 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partition in Linux, is the same things as in other PC OS: a disk contains a partition table that contains the definition of the sliced sub-parts of the drive. The number of partition is limited by the BIOS/PC architecture.

Take a modern SATA drive /dev/sda. If you have 4 partitions they will be called:

- /dev/sda1
- /dev/sda2
- /dev/sda3
- /dev/sda4

You can create a file-system on those partitions (or on the whole drive).

In Linux, there is a volume manager, called LVM that let the kernel handle drives logically and not just physically. And the logic in LVM can do far more than juste separate a single drive into smaller parts. It can create a single volume over multiple drives, create snapshot, extend a volume, reduce it's size and more.

Two SATA disks (/dev/sda and /dev/sdb) of 300 Gb can be used to create a single volume of 600 Gb.
You can turn partition or whole disk into physical volume handled by LVM:

```
pvcreate /dev/sda1
pvcreate /dev/sdb1
```

From those physical volumes you create a volume group:

```
vgcreate MyGroup /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2
```

So, MyGroup span over two drives. An almost infinite number of volumes can be created from there:

```
lvcreate --name VolumeMP3 --size 500Gb /dev/MyGroup
lvcreate --name Smaller --size 50Gb /dev/MyGroup
```

Volume can be used as old fashion partitions:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/MyGroup/Smaller
mount /dev/MyGroup/Smaller /mnt
```

During installation, RedHat handle those steps for you.

The downside of using LVM it's harder to repair a disk if you lose LVM internal data. So, it's better to backup the content of a volume than the disks themself (like using dd(1)).

Comment: Awesome answer!! Speechless...so well explained...it was just right for my level of knowledge!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A partition is a given space on a hard drive designated by entering its offset and size into a partition table. A volume is an amount of storage which usually has filesystem structures on it to allow storing files.

A partition *may* be a volume, but is not required to be one.